# Competing half reactions in electrolysis of aqueous solution of sodium hydroxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, electrolysis

If you run a direct current using pure nickel electrodes through a solution of NaOH in distilled water, you will separate the water into hydrogen and oxygen.

Are there any other reactions that could possibly take place that would release anything other than hydrogen and oxygen?

Comment: You can certainly exploit [overpotential](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overpotential)

Comment: Unless you get rid of water, likely no. @Zenix please have a look at [the Meta post regarding mobile links](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4358).

Comment: @andselisk Had I known that earlier... I will take care in future, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Zenix No prob, if this is more convenient for you, I guess it's OK to occasionally use mobile links for the comments. Just make sure you don't use them in the answers (comments are usually temporary, answers are meant to stay).

Comment: @andselisk for example in Castner Kellner, usage of Hg cathode helps in liberation of $\ce{O2}$ instead of $\ce{Cl2}$. Though there's no need to remove water (present in central compartment). But I must make it clear that I am currently not in touch of these things.

Comment: @Zenix Yeah, overpotential would have an effect if only we had, say, sodium chloride. Since it's NaOH, I don't think there is much that can deviate from traditional water splitting.